# Implementing Ports using Cells and viceversa in Oz

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm trying to figure out how to "simulate" a Port using cells but I can't make it.

The main idea is to have a function or procedure that simulates `{NewPort S P}` and other one that simulates `{Send P X}` behavior.

Here what I got.

```
declare P S
proc {CellPort ?P}
   P = {NewCell S}
end
proc {SendMessage P X}
   P := X | @P
   {Browse @P}
end
in
{CellPort P}
{Browse @P}
{SendMessage P c}
{SendMessage P b}
{SendMessage P a}
```

The Port should work like:

```
_
c|_
c|b|_
c|b|a|_
```

I don't know what else I am doing wrong that I can't make it print like above. Also, how would be implementing a cell using ports? Any guide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `SendMessage` builds a stream *backwards*.

```
P := X | @P
```

`X` is attached as a head to the existing stream. So your test code will create a stream

```
a|b|c|_
```

Instead, your program should add `X` to the unbound end of the stream. Namely, it should bind a variable inside cell `P` to a list pair which head is `X` and which tail is a new variable, a new unbound end of the stream. So a stream reader (a thread) can read a stream from its head to its tail.  This is also described in Chapter “5.1.2 Semantics of ports” in the book by  Peter Van Roy and Seif Haridi. A code for this is

```
proc {SendMessageWrong P X} End1 in
  @P = X | End1 % Line 1
  P := End1 % Line 2
end
```

Another issue with your code and `SendMessageWrong`: cell update is not atomic. Imagine what will happen when a thread executes the first line of `SendMessageWrong`, then another thread executes the first line of `SendMessageWrong`. A correct way to make it atomic is to use the built-in `Exchange` procedure.

```
{Exchange P (X | End1) End1}
```

Comment: So, a new unbound variable which will be a "new tail". Then it must be added to the cell?